# Split big line into more

Tags: notepad++

**Helllo**
I want to split a big line in multiply lines but only after a specific character and only after the 5th character.

I have a big line like this .

> @a @b @c @d @e @f @g @h @i ......

**Now i want to split this big line into more lines but ONLY after the 5th @ , like this**

> @a @b @c @d @e
>
> @f @g @h @i ...........

So i want to have on a line only 5 @ .

Please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can press Ctrl+H (Replace), then select the Regular expression option, and search for ((\@[^@]+){5}) and replace it with \1\r\n

Comment: if it works, you can mark the question as solved, so that others know it worked, without opening the question and without reading all the comments.